# split преобразовывает значение

Tags: python

Как избежать преобразования числа методом split? а то получается не то что надо

```
161Т3;-42,33;Топкова №   3;
['\ufeff161Т3', '-42,33', 'Топкова №   3']
```

в данном случае `161Т3` преобразовало в `\ufeff161Т3`

только с минусом конвертирует значения

Comment: Сделайте print(repr(...)) и увидите, что split тут совершенно ни при чём

Comment: split ничего не преобразовывает, это \ufeff там и до split у вас было.

Answer (score 1):

Это метка byte order mark, можно просто удалить.

```
s='\ufeff161Т3;-42,33;Топкова № 3'
print(s.replace('\ufeff','').split(';'))

['161Т3', '-42,33', 'Топкова № 3']
```

Answer (score 1):

решил так `with open('D:/bot_txt.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')` вместо `encoding='utf-8'`